# How to use radial CanvasGradients with Chart.js's doughnut chart?

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to create two radial gradients to use with a [Charts.js doughnut chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html).

The gradients should look kinda like the image below but in red.
[image]

Creating the gradients (`createRadialGradient`) was pretty simple using vanilla javascript and the DOM, as displayed in the code snippet below:

```js
'use strict'

const red = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 38.8%, 1)"
const redDark = "hsla(1, 60%, 30%, 1)"
const redDarker = "hsla(1, 20%, 20%, 1)"
const redLight = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 48%, 1)"

const canvasList = document.querySelectorAll('canvas.vanilla')

var {ctx, gradient} = createGradient1(canvasList[0].getContext('2d'))
ctx.fillStyle = gradient
drawRect(ctx)

var {ctx, gradient} = createGradient1(canvasList[1].getContext('2d'))
ctx.strokeStyle = gradient
ctx.lineWidth = 42
drawArc(ctx)

var {ctx, gradient} = createGradient2(canvasList[2].getContext('2d'))
ctx.fillStyle = gradient
drawRect(ctx)

var {ctx, gradient} = createGradient2(canvasList[3].getContext('2d'))
ctx.strokeStyle = gradient
ctx.lineWidth = 42
drawArc(ctx)

function createGradient1 (ctx) {
    // The inner circle is at x=110, y=90, with radius=30
    // The outer circle is at x=100, y=100, with radius=70
    // ctx.createRadialGradient(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
    const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,31, 100,100,70);

    // Add three color stops
    const innerColor = redDark
    const mainColor = red
    const outerColor = redLight
    gradient.addColorStop(0, innerColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.04, innerColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.05, mainColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, outerColor);

    return { ctx, gradient }
}
function createGradient2 (ctx) {
    // The inner circle is at x=110, y=90, with radius=30
    // The outer circle is at x=100, y=100, with radius=70
    // ctx.createRadialGradient(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
    const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,31, 100,100,70);

    // Add three color stops
    const innerColor = "hsla(1, 90%, 10%, 1)"
    const mainColor = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 20%, 1)"
    const outerColor = "transparent"
    gradient.addColorStop(0, innerColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.04, innerColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.05, mainColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.7, mainColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.73, outerColor);

    return { ctx, gradient }
}

function drawRect (ctx) {
    // ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height)
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 160, 160);
}

function drawArc (ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    // ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle [, anticlockwise])
    ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke()
}
```

```css
.vanilla {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="vanilla" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
<canvas class="vanilla" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
<canvas class="vanilla" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
<canvas class="vanilla" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```

But when I apply the same 2 gradients to [Charts.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html), I get a grey doughnut. Using a single gradient does not change the result. However, using two Hsla colors work as expected (`red` & `"white"`).

```js
/** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
const ctx = document.querySelector('.d-goal--canvas').getContext('2d')
const red = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 38.8%, 1)"
const { gradient1 } = createGradient1(ctx)
const { gradient2 } = createGradient2(ctx)
const donut = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: [
            "Pledged",
            "Missing"
        ],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Donations",
            data: [420, 80],
            cubicInterpolationMode: "monotone",
            // borderColor: [red, "white"],
            // backgroundColor: [red, "white"],
            borderColor: [gradient1, gradient2],
            backgroundColor: [gradient1, gradient2],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
})

function createGradient1 (ctx) {
    // The inner circle is at x=110, y=90, with radius=30
    // The outer circle is at x=100, y=100, with radius=70
    // ctx.createRadialGradient(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
    const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,31, 100,100,70);

    // Add three color stops
    const innerColor = "hsla(1, 60%, 30%, 1)"
    const mainColor = red
    const outerColor = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 48%, 1)"
    gradient.addColorStop(0, innerColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.04, innerColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.05, mainColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, outerColor);

    return { ctx, gradient }
}
function createGradient2 (ctx) {
    // The inner circle is at x=110, y=90, with radius=30
    // The outer circle is at x=100, y=100, with radius=70
    // ctx.createRadialGradient(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
    const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,31, 100,100,70);

    // Add three color stops
    const innerColor = "hsla(1, 90%, 10%, 1)"
    const mainColor = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 20%, 1)"
    const outerColor = "transparent"
    gradient.addColorStop(0, innerColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.04, innerColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.05, mainColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.7, mainColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(.73, outerColor);

    return { ctx, gradient }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="d-goal--canvas"></canvas>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I read [Jelena Jovanovic's gradient tutorial](https://blog.vanila.io/chart-js-tutorial-how-to-make-gradient-line-chart-af145e5c92f9), which is a linear gradient (`createLinearGradient`) applied to a line chart and I do not see what I am doing differently. Perhaps my gradient area is wrong but that should not result in a grey chart, as far as I can tell.

[The Charts.js documentation has a section about colors](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html) where they describe how to use `CanvasGradient` but only for `createLinearGradient`, which makes me think that it might be a bug in Charts.js...

Comment: Oops! I think I spot my error. `createGradient1` and `createGradient2` returns `{ ctx, gradient }` and not `gradient1` and `gradient2`! My destructure variables should be `const { gradient: gradient1 } = createGradient1(ctx)` and `const { gradient: gradient2 } = createGradient2(ctx)`

Comment: So did that fix your issue?

Comment: Only part of the issue. I now get the first gradient but not the second. And it looks wrong, which is probably because the gradient area does not match the doughnut chart area. I will post a solution when I have had time to investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way the gradient fill styles get applied to your doughnut actually. Your - and my initial - assumption is that chart.js will take care of positioning and scaling the gradient to the appropriate size to fill the doughnut. Well, that's **not** the case. Instead it uses the size & position of the gradient on the canvas.

To get a better understanding, let's take a look at your code for one of the gradients:

```
const red = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 38.8%, 1)"
const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,31, 100,100,70);
const innerColor = "hsla(1, 60%, 30%, 1)"
const mainColor = red
const outerColor = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 48%, 1)"
gradient.addColorStop(0, innerColor);
gradient.addColorStop(.04, innerColor);
gradient.addColorStop(.05, mainColor);
gradient.addColorStop(1, outerColor);
```

This will produce a gradient with a diameter of 140 pixels at x=100 and y=100 like:

[image]

Now if we dig a bit further and assume the size of the actual canvas you draw onto is 797 x 419 pixels, we can see the problem:
[image]

The gradient is **completely** out of the doughnuts shape!

To fix it, the gradient would need to be in the center of the doughnut and have the appropriate size to fill it entirely. A little something like this:
[image]

Well this is easier said then done because initially we don't know the exact size of the canvas as chart.js automatically stretches it to fill the browser window.

So what we can do to workaround goes a little something like this:

- create the doughnut using chart.js but **don't** give it a fill yet
- wait until chart.js fires a **resize event** to get the actual size of the canvas
- calculate the dimensions of the gradients according the size of the canvas and draw it at the center
- finally populate the backgroundColor of the doughnut with the gradients

Here's an example (PLease run as 'Full page' as we don't get the correct window size in stackoverflow's mini preview frame):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.d-goal--canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const red = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 38.8%, 1)"
let gradient1;
let gradient2;

function createGradient1(ctx) {
  const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 4, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  const innerColor = "hsla(1, 60%, 30%, 1)"
  const mainColor = red
  const outerColor = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 48%, 1)"
  gradient.addColorStop(0, innerColor);
  gradient.addColorStop(.12, innerColor);
  gradient.addColorStop(.121, mainColor);
  gradient.addColorStop(1, outerColor);

  return gradient;
}

function createGradient2(ctx) {
  const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 4, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  const innerColor = "hsla(1, 90%, 10%, 1)"
  const mainColor = "hsla(1, 73.7%, 20%, 1)"
  const outerColor = "transparent"
  gradient.addColorStop(0, innerColor);
  gradient.addColorStop(.12, innerColor);
  gradient.addColorStop(.121, mainColor);
  gradient.addColorStop(.99, mainColor);
  gradient.addColorStop(1, outerColor);

  return gradient;
}

function resized() {
  gradient1 = createGradient1(ctx);
  gradient2 = createGradient2(ctx);
  config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = [gradient1, gradient2];
  donut.update();
}
var config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Pledged",
      "Missing"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Donations",
      data: [420, 80],
      cubicInterpolationMode: "monotone"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onResize: resized,
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
};
const donut = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="d-goal--canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just **awesome** @obscure !

Comment: Glad I could help @dotnetCarpenter ! =)